# Auth do CakePHP não permite o funcionamento do Timthumb

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, fancybox, auth

Tenho uma galeria que funcionava correctamente, mas depois de fazer as restrições para utilizadores com o `Auth`, as miniaturas deixaram de mostrar a imagem, mas quando apago `function beforFilter()`, `public function isAuthorized($user)` e o componente `Auth`  do `AppController`, funciona. Como se resolve isto?

Estou utilizando o CakePHP 2.4.4 ,timthumb 2 e o fancybox 2.

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
                            'Session','Auth' => array(
                                                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'admin_index'),
                                                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
                                                'authorize' => array('Controller')
                                                )
                        );

public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role']==='admin'){
        return true; //admin pode acedeer a  todas as actions
    }
    return false; // os outros utilizadores não podem
}
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','login');

}
public $helpers = array('Html' ,
                        'Form' ,
                        'Timthumb.Timthumb',
                        'Paginator', 
                        'Session',
                        'Js',
                        'Fancybox.Fancybox');   


}
```

**GalleriesController**

```
    public function ShowImages(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
        $gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);
    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
    }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Galeria</h2>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        //$src3 = 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        $this->Fancybox->setProperties( array( 
            'class' => 'fancybox3',
            'className' => 'fancybox.image',
            'title'=>'Single Image',
            'rel' => 'gallery1'
            )
        );
        $this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)));

        $this->Fancybox->setMainContent($src3);
        echo $this->Fancybox->output();
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era causado pelo plugin Timthubmb do CakePHP, tendo já sido [corrigido](https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin). Também os ficheiros tiveram algumas modificações entretanto, sendo o `allow('image')` no `AppController`, e a inclusão de scripts os mais relevantes neste caso.

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar',
                            'Session','Auth' => array(
                                                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'admin_index'),
                                                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
                                                'authorize' => array('Controller')
                                                )
                        );

public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role']==='admin'){
        return true; //admin pode acedeer a  todas as actions
    }
    return false; // os outros utilizadores não podem
}
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','ShowImages','ShowShowbill','ShowVideos','login','ShowContactUs','timthumb');
    $this->Auth->allow('image');
}
public $helpers = array('Html' ,
                        'Form' ,
                        'Timthumb.Timthumb',
                        'Paginator', 
                        'Session',
                        'Js',
                        'Fancybox.Fancybox');   


}
```

**View**

```
<h2>Galeria</h2>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        //$src3 = 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        $this->Fancybox->setProperties( array( 
            'class' => 'fancybox3',
            'className' => 'fancybox.image',
            'title'=>'Single Image',
            'rel' => 'gallery1'
            )
        );
        $this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)));

        $this->Fancybox->setMainContent($src3);
        echo $this->Fancybox->output();
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>

</table>
```

**GalleriesController**

```
    public function ShowImages(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
        $gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);

    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
    }
```